# Can I include a Mono DLL and a native iOS static library in a Unity Plugin?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The Unity manual includes a section explaining how to export assets as a Unity package [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html)

I have two files I would like to export together as a single Unity package. One is a Mono DLL that sits in the top level of the Assets folder in my Unity project. The other is a native iOS static library, i.e. a `.a` file, which sits in Assets/Plugins/iOS

Following the instructions in the Unity manual mentioned above I should

> 2. Choose **Assets > Export Package…** from the menu to bring up the **Exporting Package** dialog box.
> 3. In the dialog box, select the assets you want to include in the package by clicking on the boxes so they are checked.

If I have the Mono DLL visible in the Unity editor here's what I see in the Exporting Package dialog box

[image: Unity screenshot]

But if I have the native iOS plugin visible in the Unity editor here's what I see in the Export Package dialog box

[image: Unity screenshot]

Can I include both of these items, the Mono DLL and the native iOS static library, in a single Unity package? How?

Comment: I never used unity, but dll files are windows specific, so I guess that's impossible...

Comment: Mono DLLs are not Windows specific - that's partly the purpose of Mono http://www.mono-project.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that neither of the files you want to add are visible in the Unity editor and then choose **Assets > Export Package…** from the menu to bring up the **Exporting Package** dialog box. It should then show all the possible assets to include, like this

[image: Unity screenshot]